# Dask with HTCondor scheduler

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, condor

### Background

I have an image analysis pipeline with parallelised steps. The pipeline is in `python` and the parallelisation is controlled by `dask.distributed`. The minimum processing set up has 1 scheduler + 3 workers with 15 processes each. In the first short step of the analysis I use 1 process/worker but all RAM of the node then in all other analysis steps all nodes and processes are used.

## Issue

The admin will install `HTCondor` as a scheduler for the cluster.

### Thought

In order order to have my code running on the new setup I was planning to use the approach showed in the [dask manual for SGE](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html#using-a-shared-network-file-system-and-a-job-scheduler) because the cluster has a shared network files system.

```
# job1 
# Start a dask-scheduler somewhere and write connection information to file
qsub -b y /path/to/dask-scheduler --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json

# Job2
# Start 100 dask-worker processes in an array job pointing to the same file
qsub -b y -t 1-100 /path/to/dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json

# Job3 
# Start a process with the python code where the client is started this way
client = Client(scheduler_file='/path/to/scheduler.json')
```

### Question and advice

If I understood correctly with this approach I will start scheduler, workers and analysis as independent jobs (different HTCondor submit files). How can I make sure that the order of execution will be correct? Is there a way I can use the same processing approach I have being using before or will be more efficient to translate the code to work better with HTCondor? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you aware of https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue ?

Comment: Thanks!. Just saw it! but no HTCondor support yet. https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues/100

Comment: Please comment on the thread expressing your interest. Perhaps you can help test. That would be better than trying to come up with a custom script of your own.

Comment: I will add a comment in the opened issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTCondor JobQueue support has been merged (https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/pull/245) and should now be available in Dask JobQueue (`HTCondorCluster(cores=1, memory='100MB', disk='100MB')` )

Comment: awesome! I will give it a try